# right-hand rule

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, physics

Yesterday, I was searching for a "right-rule hand" 3d model in 3d libraries all day long and unfortunately, I didn't find anything helpful.

[Right-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) is very useful in physics and a simple 3D model (glb,fbx) will make learning it much easier.

Is there anyone who can create this model for me?

Comment: Hello and welcome :). This isn't the right place for model requests. If you try making something and get stuck somewhere, you might get some useful advice. Or try [asking here](https://www.reddit.com/r/3Drequests/). Good luck.